# Display array values

Tags: php

I have two arrays like below,

First array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [desc] => teacher
        [code] => 01
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [desc] => student
        [code] => 02
    )
...

)
```

Second array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [code] => 01
        [name] => John
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [code] => 02
        [name] => Smith
    )
...
)
```

I want to get response like:

> John, teacher

and/or

> Smith, student

Please advise! Thanks.

Comment: first you'll have to explain by what you mean by "remote server". you don't "fetch php arrays" from servers.

Comment: Have you made any effort to do this?  Can you talk about what specific problem you are having in implementing a solution?

Comment: I think he just means that he want get that values of that array.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, guys! I'm newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside the mentioned issues with your question, let's just show how to associate your values. Also, your **"second"** array seems to be the more important primary one - consider renaming?

```
$first = array(
    array("desc" => "teacher", "code" => 01),
    array("desc" => "student", "code" => 02)
);

$second = array(
    array("name" => "John", "code" => 01),
    array("name" => "Smith", "code" => 02)
);

foreach($second as $value){
    echo $value['name'] . "," . $first[findDesc($first, $value['code'])]['desc'];
}

function findDesc($haystack, $needle){
   foreach($haystack as $key => $value){
      if($value['code'] === $needle )
         return $key;
   }
   return false;
}
```

So what are we doing? We loop through your second array as this seems to be your primary array, we then take the value from **"code"** and look for the same **"code"** in the first array, returning the key, thus we can get the value for **"desc"**.